# Google Line Chart: Dates not appearing correctly on x-axis

Tags: html, svg, charts, google-visualization

I am using [Google line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) and here is what I have:

[image]

The problem is that month is not placed on right spot on x-axis by google chart. As can be see on top date says **Sep 23, 2015** but straight below that it says **Oct 2015** which should have been Sep or vice versa.

So graph is not laying out correctly for some reason. I saw conf options of the chart but still I can't figure out. The dot points should correctly represent month on x-axis.

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: looks like the issue is resolved but I've also seen [date formats](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32430511/5090771) cause the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay figured out, I had to use `hAxis.gridlines` option.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this is incorrect, but still you might prefer to alter it.

In this chart, the date axis points are located at Apr 1st, Jul 1st, Oct 1st 2014 etc. For the sake of brevity, however, they are abbreviated to just "Apr 2014", "May 2014", ... "Sep 2015".

Therefore Sep 23 is correctly just before "Oct 2015", i.e. "Oct 1st 2015".

Try to change the formatting of the axis labels if you wish.