# Google line chart time is showing

Tags: javascript, api, linechart

I'm working on google line chart and it is working fine but I want to hide time, when I hover at point it is showing complete date and time, I want only date not time how to hide time I search a lot but didn't find any solution and tried different parameters which I found on different forums but none of them work for me.

you can all see screen shot
[image: google line chart]

as you can see date and time are mention and usage is 600 only date should be shown not time and my code is

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chartDiv');
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('date', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', "Sent");
        data.addColumn('number', "Signed");
        data.addColumn('number', "ID");
        data.addColumn('number', "Usage");

        data.addRows([
            [new Date(2017, 1, 2),   24,   57,    2,   12],
            [new Date(2017, 2, 4),   87,   87,    4,   45],
            [new Date("2017-03-05"),   54,   12,    6,   67],
            [new Date("2017-04-08"),   32,  153,    6,   87]
        ]);

        var materialOptions = {
                chart: {
                title: 'Chart of: (User 1)'
            },
            width: 1200,
            height: 600
        };

        function drawMaterialChart() {
            var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
            materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
        }
        drawMaterialChart();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution may be to treat the date as a string, so

```
    data.addColumn('string', 'Month'); //<-- change type date for string
    data.addColumn('number', "Sent");
    data.addColumn('number', "Signed");
    data.addColumn('number', "ID");
    data.addColumn('number', "Usage");

    data.addRows([ // then change all new Date() for strings
        ["1/2/2017",   24,   57,    2,   12],
        ["2/4/2017",   87,   87,    4,   45],
        ["3/5/2017"),   54,   12,    6,   67],
        ["4/8/2017"),   32,  153,    6,   87]
    ]);
```

Comment: cannot do that because I need months name and in javascript I get month name easily so is their any other solution and easily to play/manipulate with javascript date function.

Comment: I found this too but parameters are different from my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133792/how-do-i-align-date-and-values-to-gridlines-in-google-chart and showing only date not time and type is also date.