# How do I align Google Chart gridlines with my data points?

Tags: date, charts, google-visualization, gridlines

While I have read several similar SO posts (most notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133792/how-do-i-align-date-and-values-to-gridlines-in-google-chart), which is the reason for the first, commented-out `dataArray` in my snippet), I still cannot seem to make my gridlines along the horizontal axis align with my actual data points.  As you can see from the snippet below, I have specified the `hAxis.ticks`.  While it's no longer reflected in this snippet, I've also played around with `hAxis.gridlines.count`, `hAxis.minorGridlines.count`, and several other options, all to no avail.

```js
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  data.addColumn('date', 'Dates');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Ratings');
  
  /* const dataArray = [
    [new Date('2020-12-22'),  2],
    [new Date('2020-01-05'),  6],
    [new Date('2020-01-05'),  7],
    [new Date('2020-02-02'),  8],
    [new Date('2020-02-16'), 10],
    [new Date('2020-03-01'),  5],
    [new Date('2020-03-15'),  9],
  ] */
  
  const dataArray = [
    [new Date('12/22/2019'),  2],
    [new Date('01/05/2020'),  6],
    [new Date('01/19/2020'),  7],
    [new Date('02/02/2020'),  8],
    [new Date('02/16/2020'), 10],
    [new Date('03/01/2020'),  5],
    [new Date('03/15/2020'),  9],
  ];
  
  data.addRows(dataArray);
  
  const dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  
  const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart'));
  
  chart.draw(dataView, {
    pointSize:        5,
    lineWidth:        3,
    hAxis:            {
      format:    "MMM d, yyyy",
      ticks:     dataArray.map(d => d[0])
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

appears to be an issue with the `'current'` version of google charts.
if you go back to version `'45'`, it appears to work as expected.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('45', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  const data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  
  data.addColumn('date', 'Dates');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Ratings');
  
  /* const dataArray = [
    [new Date('2020-12-22'),  2],
    [new Date('2020-01-05'),  6],
    [new Date('2020-01-05'),  7],
    [new Date('2020-02-02'),  8],
    [new Date('2020-02-16'), 10],
    [new Date('2020-03-01'),  5],
    [new Date('2020-03-15'),  9],
  ] */
  
  const dataArray = [
    [new Date('12/22/2019'),  2],
    [new Date('01/05/2020'),  6],
    [new Date('01/19/2020'),  7],
    [new Date('02/02/2020'),  8],
    [new Date('02/16/2020'), 10],
    [new Date('03/01/2020'),  5],
    [new Date('03/15/2020'),  9],
  ];
  
  data.addRows(dataArray);
  
  const dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  
  const chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart'));
  
  chart.draw(dataView, {
    pointSize:        5,
    lineWidth:        3,
    hAxis:            {
      format:    "MMM d, yyyy",
      ticks:     dataArray.map(d => d[0])
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```